# How to click a button until the button isn't visible?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm trying to write a step that clicks a more button until that button changes to `display: none;`.

**CLARIFICATION:** The page I'm working with is a [Google+ business page](https://plus.google.com/101200069268247335090/about?hl=en). There is a more button that loads about 10 reviews at a time until they are all loaded. Once they are, Google sets the button to `display: none;`

I've played around with a ton of different ways to accomplish it. Right now I'm working with something like:

This one is not working, and I'm sure there is an elegant way to accomplish this.

```
casper.then(function() {
  while (this.visible('.d-s.L5.r0')){
    console.log("Click");
    this.click('.d-s.L5.r0');
  }
});
```

This new code is working, but I have to set how many times it repeats which is pretty hacky:

```
casper.repeat(15, function() {
   console.log("Click");
   this.click('.d-s.L5.r0');
   this.wait(400);
});
```

Comment: Look into a callback approach where after every click you tigger the callback that checks the status of the button

Comment: @TGH Could you provide some sudo code possibly? I'm a super n00b with casper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need proper status handling of the button. By clicking the *more* button it will be invisible, but another *loading* `span` will be visible until the next items are loaded. Then it is exchanged again. You need to reflect the change in your code.

```
if (this.visible(moreButton)) { // synchronous
    // asynchronous steps...
    this.thenClick(moreButton);
    this.waitUntilVisible(loadingButton);
    this.waitUntilVisible(moreButton);
    this.then(function(){
        this.capture("business.png"); // overwrite the current screenshot
        // recursion here
    });
}
```

Additionally, it is good practice to write the thing recursive, because you don't know the number of steps until you try the steps. So the complete code would be:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    waitTimeout: 10000,
    viewportSize: {
        width: 900,
        height: 720
    }
});

var moreButton = '[id*="about-page"] span.d-s.L5.r0',
    loadingButton = moreButton + ' + span.dP.PA';

function clickMore(max, i){
    i = i || 0;
    if ((max == null || i < max) && this.visible(moreButton)) { // synchronous
        // asynchronous steps...
        this.thenClick(moreButton);  // sometimes the click is not properly dispatched
        this.waitUntilVisible(loadingButton);
        this.waitUntilVisible(moreButton, null, function onTimeout(){
            // only placeholder so that the script doesn't "die" here if the end is reached
        });
        this.then(function(){
            this.capture("business_"+i+".png");
            clickMore.call(this, max, i+1); // recursion
        });
    }
}

casper.start("https://plus.google.com/101200069268247335090/about?hl=en").then(function(){
    clickMore.call(casper);
}).then(function(){
    this.capture("business_end.png");
}).run(function(){
    this.echo("DONE");
    this.exit();
});
```

You can also call `clickMore` with an argument setting the maximum number of clicks like this:

```
clickMore.call(casper, 10);
```

A problem remains. The click on the *more* button is sometimes not dispatched. You should explore other approaches clicking that button.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer. I'll be trying it out ASAP. What do you mean that the button is sometimes not dispatched?

Comment: I mean that the script worked fine as is the first 3 runs or so, but then every run failed at the 3rd or 4th recursion level. I couldn't solve. Maybe google activated some anti-scraping hacks or there is something else with the script.

Comment: Thanks so much for the best SO answer I've ever received. I'd love to have you help with this application I'm building.

Comment: Thanks so much for your very detailed answer. My friend and I are students in a JS dev boot camp right now, and we're working on our final project. Would you be interested in helping us out from time to time on skype or email? WE have a small company so we could even pay you for your time. Let me know. -Eric

Comment: We moved to spookyJS, moved our functions into spooky and now our only issue is that we're getting an error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.visible(moreButton)')`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: In spookyjs you have to be aware that there are 3 contexts now: page, casper and spooky. I don't know the details.

Comment: Yes, now learning that very well haha. What is the ``max, i`` mean and where does it come from in your function?

Comment: You can set the maximum number of *more* clicks. If you leave out the `max` argument in the first call to `clickMore`, it will click every *more* button until there is none to click anymore. Otherwise it will stop at `max` "pages".