# Casper js to Automate to click load more button until the whole records get loaded.

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I got a webpage on pressing load more the ajax content will load another set of records and append with the previous one.
My requirement is to get the whole records until a "no record" message found.

```
casper.start('http://www.example.com/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle()); 
});

casper.then(function(){

    _events = this.evaluate(function() {
        var events = [];
        [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('.home-portfolio'), 
        function fn(elem){
            var obj = {
                'event_name': elem.querySelector('h2').textContent,
                'start_date': elem.querySelector('time[itemprop="startDate"]').getAttribute('datetime'),
                'end_date': elem.querySelector('time[itemprop="endDate"]').getAttribute('datetime'),
                'detail_url': elem.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href')
            }
            events.push(obj);
        });
        return events;
    });

});
```

The above code just return the first loaded records. I need my script to automatically press the load more button and give the whole record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to click a button until the button isn't visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644557/how-to-click-a-button-until-the-button-isnt-visible)

Comment: Another way: [How can I make casperjs repeat a loop until a certain condition is met?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625935/how-can-i-make-casperjs-repeat-a-loop-until-a-certain-condition-is-met)